# Change leading numbers in file names to fixed width

Tags: regex, bash, rename, batch-processing, file-rename

I have a large set of audio files that all begin with a variable length number, followed by a space-dash-space (i.e. `" - "`). The text after this is variable. Some of the files include:

```
12 - Buckle my Shoe.mp3
42 - The Meaning of Life.m4a
12321 - Palindromes and other stuff.wav
```

How can I convert, for example, all of the file names so that the leading integer is padded up to 6 characters in width, with leading zeros? i.e.:

```
000012 - Buckle my Shoe.mp3
000042 - The Meaning of Life.m4a
012321 - Palindromes and other stuff.wav
```

I'm doing this because my audiobook player doesn't sort files properly unless the numbers in the file name are leading-zero-padded and fixed width.

I have something that's a lengthy [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script that almost accomplishes this, but I was hoping there's a simpler one-liner I could use via the command-line. Also, I was hoping to learn the minimal regex for this.

Also, if there's a quick-and-easy way to calculate the longest leading integer and use that instead of my arbitrary `6`, that's a plus too!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Perl version of `rename`, you can do something like this:

```
rename 's/^(\d+)/sprintf "%06d", $1/e' *
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternate approach from  `rename`: Using `awk`'s `sprintf` function to pad the first field.

```
for file in * ;
  do 
   mv "$file" "$(awk '{$1=sprintf("%06d", $1)}1' <<<  "$file")";
done
```

Input files:

```
 ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ps ps 0 Jun 14 01:56 12321 - Palindromes and other stuff.wav
-rw-r--r-- 1 ps ps 0 Jun 14 01:56 12 - Buckle my Shoe.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ps ps 0 Jun 14 01:56 42 - The Meaning of Life.m4a
```

Output files:

```
 ls -lrt
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 ps ps 0 Jun 14 01:56 012321 - Palindromes and other stuff.wav
-rw-r--r-- 1 ps ps 0 Jun 14 01:56 000012 - Buckle my Shoe.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 ps ps 0 Jun 14 01:56 000042 - The Meaning of Life.m4a
```